# Knowledges graphs and chatbots

Tags: artificial-intelligence, graph-databases, chatbot

I'm hardly trying to figure out what would be a functionnal and technical architecture of a chatbot that would has a knowledge graph as back end (graph DB like Grakn or Neo4j, I don't know which one is better yet).

For the moment I am going with Neo4j as database but I saw an interesting tutorial with grakn.ai where the guy is using Api.ai + graph DB (see : https://blog.grakn.ai/chatbots-and-grakn-ai-67563c64cfde).

I'm also looking at this github which is using Ontology + botkit + dialogflow (see: https://github.com/D2KLab/music-chatbot). I don't understand why this person is using botkit.

So, i'm lost... What stack should i use to build my chatbot architecture?

PS: in addition, I need to make a dataviz of my bot's brain

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)